# Trying to compile ASPNetWebStack getting 35MSSharedLib1024.snk missing private Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Have been trying to compile source from https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

- Loaded Runtime.csproj,
- added a project to be able to step through MVC source.
- Disabled Delay Signing,
- then built, and received.

Error   1   Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 'c:...\aspnetwebstack-master\src\System.Web.Mvc\obj\Debug\System.Web.Mvc.dll' -- 'Key file 'c:...\aspnetwebstack-master\src\System.Web.Mvc\35MSSharedLib1024.snk' is missing the private key needed for signing' C:\Files\Projects\aspnetwebstack-master\src\System.Web.Mvc\CSC  System.Web.Mvc

(p.s. build.cmd built successfully but with skipstongnames enabled, but the project doesn't build for System.Web.Mvc and ofcourse for its dependencies).

Sorry for the open ended question but, what may I be doing wrong here

Answer (score 2):

ok looks like Disabling Delay Signing was a mistake.

This link helped me through though

http://www.codedistillers.com/?p=53

Tried to reproduce the issue copying the source to another place, and retried the procedure.

Was thinking of recommending not to open Runtime.sln and built it from the IDE before running build.cmd from the Admin privileged command line, **but** found out that you should be able to build from the IDE without a problem and get your binaries in the aspnetwebstack-master/bin/Debug and can reference them in your project.

All seems to be working fine now. Added this for future reference and if someone else may stumble upon such a problem.

One more thing, if you build your source from build.cmd and your *** Build failed *** chances are there is a message asking you to postfix Skipskipstrongnames /e to the build command do so and it will succeed.

Some old walkthroughs misdirect by asking you to download Skipstrongnames.exe from the internet with failing links. Not to worry. Once you start the build process, either be it from the IDE or this build.cmd, the Nuget packages will be loaded and the Skipstrongnames.exe will be located in the aspnetwebstack-master/packages/Microsoft.Web.SkipStrongName.1.0.0/tools folder. version may vary overtime but just for reference thought to mention it here.

Hope this helps somebody